# pros and cons for converting to normal maps?

Tags: workflow, texture-baking

I have seen many users on youtube advice to bake after sculpting high poly meshes to speed up the render time but since a normal map is just xyz encoded as rgb how is it different ?

are normal maps capable of keeping all the details from the high poly models?
do they have limitations like not being able to cast shadows?

Comment: You might want to check the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) if you haven't already.

Comment: Normal maps are a way to reduce geometry while keeping the shading almost equal to the original mesh. The illusion will break though when the silhouette doesn´t really match with the outline of the original object anymore.

Comment: Aha, okay,then i should avoid them if i am aiming for realistic look right?.

Comment: Well it is a trade-off - realism vs. render time. It is usually used in realtime engines to speed up rendering tremendously. If you are careful enough you wont notice a difference. Human vision can be tricked easy enough.